# preg_match_all to make array of street addresses

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match

I need to capture the parts of street addresses into php variables. I'm most of the way there with preg_match_all, but I could use some help with the regex portion:

```
$address[0] = '2033 2nd Avenue, Seattle, WA 98121';

preg_match_all("/(\w*)+/", $address[0], $first_address);

// get rid of the empty bits
$first_address = array_filter(array_map('array_filter',$first_address));

print_r($first_address)

// results
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2033
            [2] => 2nd
            [4] => Avenue
            [7] => Seattle
            [10] => WA
            [12] => 98121
      )
  )
```

I can access the parts fine using syntax like `$first_address[0][4]`, but I can't rely on the array numbers representing the address parts being the same (sometimes the commas are left out).

What would be ideal is if I could produce an associative array that names the parts:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hsn]    => 2033
            [street] => 2nd
            [suffix] => Avenue
            [city]   => Seattle
            [state]  => WA
            [zip]    => 98121
      )
  )
```

Does anybody have a better way of doing this?

Comment: You need a complicated parser. For instance, if it's `2033 West 2nd Avenue`, you need to make `street => West 2nd`.

Comment: And what about `100 Avenue of the Americas, NY, NY`?

Comment: Yup you can go with associative array but i looked your stuff upside. in your case. explode(','$address[0]) will be very great. simple and very easy

Comment: Yep, i tried this, still haven't completed the parser yet, and it's only for Australian street addresses but does work a treat. The easiest way i found is to hit google maps api with an address and it will kindly return the address parsed for you, but there is a limit on how many you can do a day. While parsing an address is fairly trivial, accounting for humans and their inconsistencies is hard work, actually that's all programmers do, account for human foolishness/laziness.